# How to draw a scatter graph with 2 y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colormap

I am trying to plot a scatter graph with X, Y and Y2. The main objective is to study the relationship between these three features.

```
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [110, 120, 130, 140, 150]
Y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
Y2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

plt.title('X vs Y vs Y2')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
points1 = plt.scatter(X, Y,
                      c=Y, cmap="rainbow", alpha=1) #set style options

cbar = plt.colorbar(points1)
cbar.set_label('Y2')
```

But I got something like this:

[image: current output]

The points of the graph show the relationship between X and Y. I want Y2 relation to be shown by using the colorbar labelled at the right side of the y-axis. I expected it to look like this:

[image: expected output]

Comment: let c=Y2, points1 = plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Y2, cmap="rainbow", alpha=1) #set style options